# Careers site spamming - not sure what I opted out of

Tags: support, jobs, spam, email

While I love the SO Careers website, I feel that these sorts of emails are entirely inappropriate. So I clicked the link at the bottom to "opt out" of these emails, but I'm not sure what I opted out of - did I just opt out of spam emails or will I be ignoring any possible recruiters from now on because I'm not getting emails?

[image: Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, baked beans, Spam, Spam, Spam and Spam]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you have not opted out of receiving emails from recruiters that find your profile on Careers.  The only way to do that is to make your profile unsearchable in the privacy settings on Careers.  I believe this is what you were hoping was the case.

Second, it completely sucks that that wasn't clear to you.  What did you just opt out of?  We have transactional emails, emails from employers, marketing emails etc... We need to tell you what you're opting out of so you can stop getting this, and just get the stuff you want.  So, we'll work on making that more clear.

Lastly, these nag emails are too spammy.  We do want you to update your profile to make sure you're representing yourself accurately to employers, and so you have a better chance of being contacted, but we're pushing too hard.  I'll look into making these less frequent, more personalized, and easy to turn off.

We never want to spam you.  We did here, and we'll get it fixed.

Comment: Will: FWIW, I think the OP was only referring to the emails prodding him to update his profile, and that's what I'd assume that the opt-out link does.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Agree.  Which is what I wanted to assure him was happening in the first section.  It is annoying though that we don't actually segment the types of emails  we send and how to get rid of only a few of them.  Seems like we did what he wanted, but it's still confusing.

Comment: Answers like this are the reason SO Careers is so great.